# Запись в файл в потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность, filestream

Приветствую! Проблема следующая - запускаю метод в новый поток

```
 currentThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Started));
 currentThread.Start();
```

В методе происходит работа с неким стримом

```
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(path + nameFile))
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
```

И на строке CopyTo вылетает с ошибкой  “cannot access closed file”.
В чем проблема, как решить ?

Comment: Код выглядит рабочим. Ошибка где-то в другом месте. Скорее всего - там, где вы закрываете `stream`

Comment: в последовательном виде все работало, вынес в поток и вот... так что проблема в этом, но как решить пока не знаю

Comment: Повторяю: *код рабочий, ошибка в другом месте*

Comment: Покажите весь метод `Started`, а именно как инициализируется и используется `stream`.

Comment: выбираем файл, который находится на диске (file), и в виде file.InputStream посылаем в метод ImportData. В этом методе Stream сохраняется в локальную переменную и ещё подписываемся на другой метод  ServiceHub.Started += StartImport, где "ServiceHub.Started" это public static event Action Started. После чего в нужный момент запускаем thread как я описал в вопросе. Ну и в StartImport мы берем локальную переменную stream и используем её опять же как я описал в вопросе, все

Comment: Просто покажите код.

Comment: Как-то так http://pastebin.com/Jgi62wvf

Comment: А вы уверены, что падает не на `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` и что стрим еще открыт? Стримы приходят откуда-то извне, вы их не контролируете и они могут быть в любом состоянии.

Comment: уверен, иду по брекпоинтам. stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); проходит и ПОСЛЕ следующей строчки валится. И если  ServiceHub.Started += StartImport; заменить на обычный вызов StartImport(); , то все идеально

Comment: А откуда-таки берутся эти стримы? И еще вопрос: сколько данных в стриме, который падает?

Comment: Сейчас стандарт это асинхронное программирование, а вы все потоки используете https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh159084(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: стрим берется из файла (обычный файл с данными с раширением .csv) посредством InputStream (file.InputStream ), это передается в метод и дальше уже гуляет как Stream. Данных там с 3к строк

Comment: Вы закачиваете файлы в ASP.NET приложении что ли? Попробуйте увеличить requestLengthDiskThreshold.